# How to programatically enable share location in browser?

Tags: php, javascript, html, .net

I want to use geolocator in browser for detecting location of the user. Is it possible to enable browser share location internally by using code?

Comment: I don't think so. There would be no sense with such limitations if you could change it from script.

Comment: You mean without it asking the user if they wish to reveal their location? No!

Answer (score 0):

No, The geolocation API explicitly states: “User Agents must not send location information to Web sites without the express permission of the user.” In other words, sharing your location is always opt-in. If you don’t want to, you don’t have to.

http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html